# Cambio de option de un select por texto y no atributo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Con este `<select>`

```
<select id="idselect">
  <option value="1" data-msg="111">Personalizado</option>
</select>
```

Para cambiar a la opción a un `<select>` en jquery tengo por ejemplo estas opciones

```
$('#idselect').val('1').attr('selected','selected')
$('#idselect > option[value="1"]').attr('selected','selected')
$('#idselect > option[data-msg="111"]').attr('selected','selected')
```

Pero es con `value` o atributos personalizados

Me gustaría saber como se puede cambiar la opción indicándole el texto 'Personalizado' y no por ningún atributo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo, el meollo del asunto está en el uso del selector jQuery `contains`

```js
$("a[data-select]").click(function(){
  var texto_de_option = this.getAttribute('data-select').trim();
  $("#idselect").find('option:contains("'+texto_de_option+'")').prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select id="idselect">
      <option value="1" data-msg="111">Personalizado1</option>
      <option value="2" data-msg="222">Personalizado2</option>
      <option value="3" data-msg="333">Personalizado3</option>
      <option value="4" data-msg="444">Personalizado4</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <a href = "javascript:;" data-select='Personalizado1'>Seleccionar Personalizado1</a>
    <br><br>
    <a href = "javascript:;" data-select='Personalizado2'>Seleccionar Personalizado2</a>
    <br><br>
    <a href = "javascript:;" data-select='Personalizado3'>Seleccionar Personalizado3</a>
    <br><br>
    <a href = "javascript:;" data-select='Personalizado4'>Seleccionar Personalizado4</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar el selector [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) para comprobar el texto dentro del `<option>`.

```js
$(function(){
  
  $('button').on('click', function(){
    
     $('#idselect option:contains("Personalizado")').attr('selected','selected');
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<select id="idselect">
  <option>select</option>
  <option value="1" data-msg="111">Personalizado</option>
  <option value="2" data-msg="112">otra cosa</option>
</select>
  
<button>Elegir Personalizado</button>
```